# Spring AOP around @StreamListener method - Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring, spring-aop, spring-cloud-stream

I have a Spring Cloud Stream Consumer as below

```
    @Component
    @Slf4j
    public class IngestionStatusEventHandler {

      @StreamListener(TestMessageStreams.INGESTIONSTATUS)
      public void handleEvent(@Payload IngestionStatusMessage message, @Header(name = "tenant-id") String tenantId) throws Exception {
        log.info("New ingestion status event received: {}", message);

      }
```

I want to be able to advice the handleEvent method with an @Around Spring AOP to do some pre and post processing. Is it possible to do this and if so how?

I have already tried applying an AspectJ aspect as below

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class SomeAspect {

  @Around(value = "execution(* com.handler.IngestionStatusEventHandler.handleEvent(..)) && this(eventHandler) && args(message))")
  public void around(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, IngestionStatusEventHandler<Object> eventHandler, Message<Object> message) {

  }
}
```

but it doesnt seem to be invoked. When i tried to debug, I saw that the StreamListenerMessageHandler's invocableHandlerMethod contains an instance of IngestionStatusEventHandler and not the Spring JDK Dynamic Proxy which could be the issue. Can someone advice as to how to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: Could you try adding `args(message,..)`  instead of `args(message)` . Also have you enabled Spring AOP through `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` ?

Comment: Hi R.G, I tried applying both your suggestions but no luck. As I mentioned in the issue, i see that the invocableHandlerMethod does not have a proxy for the bean variable which I suspect could be the issue;

Comment: How does the `invocableHandlerMethod` get the bean instance ?  I don't know how to run this code and debug , to help you with find a solution if I can. Just want to mention that your other question and the 'actual' issue at hand are totally different. The aspect code I shared for your other question was correct and tested locally. For this I do not have the knowledge to get a running application .

Comment: Hi R.G, The point cut expression is all correct. The @StreamListener annotation is processed by Spring Cloud Stream and that sets the bean inside invocableHandlerMethod.

Comment: I am not able to share any code as it requires some kafka environment to be able to run it and its private;

Comment: try if the method gets adviced with `execution()` alone , to make sure the other conditions applied are valid for that class at runtime.remember to remove the method arguments to match the point cut.